How do we move only one word consist letters and numbers after the word "school" to new column?
How do we move only one word consist letters and numbers after the word "school" to new column H?
How do we modify our program to achieve that?
Sub Copyvalue()
    Dim lookfor As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim cellval As Variant
    Dim lastrow As Integer
    lookfor = "/"
    ' Column C
    Const colNo = 3
 
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, colNo).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        ' Split the string into an array
        If InStr(Cells(i, colNo), lookfor) > 0 Then
            cellval = Split(Cells(i, colNo).Value, lookfor)
        End If
        
        If Not IsEmpty(cellval) Then
            For j = UBound(cellval) To LBound(cellval) Step -1
                If cellval(j) <> "" Then
                    Cells(i, colNo + 5) = cellval(j)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
            cellval = Empty
        End If
    Next i
End Sub 



Try this way:
Sub Copyvalue()
    Dim lookfor As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim cellval As Variant
    Dim lastrow As Integer
    lookfor = " "
    ' Column C
    Const colNo = 3
 
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, colNo).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        ' Split the string into an array
        If InStr(Cells(i, colNo), lookfor) > 0 Then
            cellval = Split(Cells(i, colNo).Value, lookfor)
        End If
        
        If Not IsEmpty(cellval) Then
            For j = UBound(cellval) To LBound(cellval) Step -1
             '   If cellval(j) = "school" Then    ' old version
                If cellval(j) = "school" And j < UBound(cellval) Then   ' updated
                    Cells(i, colNo + 5) = cellval(j + 1)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
            cellval = Empty
        End If
    Next i
End Sub



sometime after school empty space how do we remake program?

running the last code resulting the errar
run-time error '9'
subscript out ot range on line
Cells(i, colNo + 5) = cellval(j + 1)

I don't understand how your data looks like in this case, show us a new example.

but after school word can be no string as result the program stop with error out of range

how do we modefy program if after school no letters the program run to next string and do not stop with error?

So, you mean, "school" is the last word in the cell?

yes the program strop with error, how do we bypass error and continue incerting column in sheet?

i remake the picture

You should add a new condition: If cellval(j) = "school" And j < UBound(cellval) Then, see updated code.

You can also accomplish this with formulas:
If you have 365:
=LET(
    spl, TEXTSPLIT(C2, " "),
    pos, MATCH(G2, spl, 0),
    IFERROR(INDEX(spl, pos + 1), "")
)

or, for older versions of Excel:
=IFERROR(
    FILTERXML(
        "<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(C2, " ", "</s><s>") & "</s></t>",
        "//s[preceding-sibling::*[1]='" & G2 & "']"
    ),
    ""
)

Note that, depending on your locale, the argument separator in the formulas above might be the semicolon (;) instead of the comma (,) as shown.
